# Cordova app can't make CORS request in First Run

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm having a problem with Cordova and (maybe?) cordova-plugin-whitelist since yesterday and can't figure out a solution, so here I'm, searching for your help. I'll try my best to explain everything.

**Background**

I work on an IT company and we have some applications developed using Cordova Platform. Yesterday, I installed an application on my device and get the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://valid-url/' from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
    at Request.push../node_modules/superagent/lib/client.js.Request.crossDomainError (client.js:621)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:705)
```

This errors don't allow me to make a request to the server. But here's a curious thing: **this just happens when I start the application for the first time** or when I **delete the database**; if I close the application and start it again it works just fine. Another curious thing: this happens with all ours applications, and some of then don't get a new patch or any change in months, so... how could it happen? I though about a change on Chromium, but the version on my device is older than the actual one.

I know that I need cordova-plugin-whitelist to make requests, I already have it installed on the **1.3.4** version and with this configurations on config.xml (on one of the applications):

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

My current version of **cordova-android** is 7.0.0 - I already tried to downgrade cordova-android and plugin whitelist to 6.4.0 and 1.3.3 respectively, but doesn't worked.

I suspect that the problem is in android itself or cordova-plugin-whitelist, but remember: it started from nothing, without any changes in the code repositories or new builds - this is driving me crazy.

Can someone give me a light?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're having this same issue at my company. Looking into it, we've discovered this Chromium bug that has a fix merged into 77:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107

If you're running Chromium 76, this might be the source of your troubles. Sadly, it's not fixable on our end.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it helped me a lot. Sad that we need to do this workaround for a while...

Comment: No problem! If this sufficiently answered your question, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?